Android emulator closing on startup
I've been having an issue with AVDs on IntelliJ IDEA. Each time I run an emulator it maybe comes up on the google boot screen and the logo sort of glitches and closes or it just doesn't start. It was working before, although before the chrome on the emulated device showed corrupted images each time I searched for anything so maybe some files got corrupted. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the device, creating new ones, reinstalling SDKs, i even uninstalled the whole android plugin, deleted all of the folders and reinstalled everything from scratch but its still not working. The Logcat doesn't seem to show any specific error to indicate why this could be happening to I turned to the IntelliJ logs but i don't understand it very well. The app is using react-native with expo (although its not even running, I am just trying to run the emulator).
This are the IntelliJ logs for when I start the emulator, maybe someone who understands better than me can tell me what I can do.
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 50ae:62d6:8f01:0:907d:62d6:8f01:0 (2x)
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Critical:
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Warning:
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Warning:  (6x)
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - library_mode swiftshader_indirect gpu mode swiftshader_indirect
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoGPU #1
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Make: 8086
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Model: Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Device ID: a7a0
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:32:59.612302   10308 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: SwiftShader Device (LLVM 10.0.0)
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062114   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062132   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062134   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062703   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062714   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062716   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062718   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062719   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062721   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062723   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062724   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.062726   10308 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.065865   10308 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc. (Intel))
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.065875   10308 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (ANGLE (Intel, Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-31.0.101.4255))
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.065878   10308 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.17734 git hash: 1bd1a3db1c60))
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.065880   10308 FrameBuffer.cpp:509] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
2024-06-28 15:33:00,064 [7575055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.065883   10308 FrameBuffer.cpp:510] Graphics Device Extensions N
2024-06-28 15:33:00,229 [7575220]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - /A
2024-06-28 15:33:00,230 [7575221]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
2024-06-28 15:33:00,230 [7575221]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - WHPX on Windows 10.0.22631 detected.
2024-06-28 15:33:00,230 [7575221]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
2024-06-28 15:33:00,335 [7575326]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - netsimd I 06-28 18:33:00.329 rust_main.rs:96 - netsim artifacts path: "C:\\Users\\ramal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\netsimd"
2024-06-28 15:33:00,335 [7575326]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - netsimd I 06-28 18:33:00.335 rust_main.rs:99 - NetsimdArgs {
2024-06-28 15:33:00,335 [7575326]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - fd_startup_str: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,335 [7575326]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_cli_ui: true,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,335 [7575326]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_web_ui: true,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - pcap: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - disable_address_reuse: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - hci_port: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - connector_instance: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - instance: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - logtostderr: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - dev: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - vsock: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - config: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - test_beacons: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_test_beacons: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_shutdown: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - version: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:00,336 [7575327]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - }
2024-06-28 15:33:00,533 [7575524]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
2024-06-28 15:33:00,575 [7575566]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Using security allow list from: C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\emulator_access.json
2024-06-28 15:33:00,581 [7575572]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
2024-06-28 15:33:00,590 [7575581]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\380\jwks\9a28bf8d-ddb6-463d-961e-557532474f21\active.jwk
2024-06-28 15:33:00,590 [7575581]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Scanning C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\380\jwks\9a28bf8d-ddb6-463d-961e-557532474f21 for jwk keys.
2024-06-28 15:33:00,606 [7575597]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
2024-06-28 15:33:00,617 [7575608]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Advertising in: C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_380.ini
2024-06-28 15:33:00,666 [7575657]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.665886   25000 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 1
2024-06-28 15:33:00,666 [7575657]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - 080 h 2340 dpiX 440 dpiY 440
2024-06-28 15:33:00,666 [7575657]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - I0628 15:33:00.666397   25000 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##############################################################################
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##                        WARNING - ACTION REQUIRED                         ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  Consider using the '-metrics-collection' flag to help improve the       ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  emulator by sending anonymized usage data. Or use the '-no-metrics'     ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  flag to bypass this warning and turn off the metrics collection.        ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  In a future release this warning will turn into a one-time blocking     ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,710 [7575701]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  prompt to ask for explicit user input regarding metrics collection.     ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,711 [7575702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##                                                                          ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,711 [7575702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  Please see '-help-metrics-collection' for more details. You can use     ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,711 [7575702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  '-metrics-to-file' or '-metrics-to-console' flags to see what type of   ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,711 [7575702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##  data is being collected by emulator as part of usage statistics.        ##
2024-06-28 15:33:00,711 [7575702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - ##############################################################################
2024-06-28 15:33:01,033 [7576024] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction - `ActionUpdateThread.OLD_EDT` is deprecated and going to be removed soon. 'com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction' must override `getActionUpdateThread` and chose EDT or BGT. See ActionUpdateThread javadoc. [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: `ActionUpdateThread.OLD_EDT` is deprecated and going to be removed soon. 'com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction' must override `getActionUpdateThread` and chose EDT or BGT. See ActionUpdateThread javadoc. [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginProblemReporterImpl.createPluginExceptionByClass(PluginProblemReporterImpl.java:23)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException.createByClass(PluginException.java:90)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException.reportDeprecatedUsage(PluginException.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionUpdateThreadAware.getActionUpdateThread(ActionUpdateThreadAware.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction.getActionUpdateThread(AnAction.java:199)
2024-06-28 15:33:01,035 [7576026] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction - IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1  Build #IU-241.14494.240
2024-06-28 15:33:01,036 [7576027] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction - JDK: 17.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-06-28 15:33:01,036 [7576027] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction - OS: Windows 11
2024-06-28 15:33:01,036 [7576027] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction - Plugin to blame: Android version: 241.14494.240
2024-06-28 15:33:01,036 [7576027] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.ui.screenshot.ScreenshotAction - Last Action: ShowLog
2024-06-28 15:33:01,056 [7576047] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction - `ActionUpdateThread.OLD_EDT` is deprecated and going to be removed soon. 'com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction' must override `getActionUpdateThread` and chose EDT or BGT. See ActionUpdateThread javadoc. [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: `ActionUpdateThread.OLD_EDT` is deprecated and going to be removed soon. 'com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction' must override `getActionUpdateThread` and chose EDT or BGT. See ActionUpdateThread javadoc. [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginProblemReporterImpl.createPluginExceptionByClass(PluginProblemReporterImpl.java:23)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException.createByClass(PluginException.java:90)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException.reportDeprecatedUsage(PluginException.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionUpdateThreadAware.getActionUpdateThread(ActionUpdateThreadAware.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction.getActionUpdateThread(AnAction.java:199)
2024-06-28 15:33:01,057 [7576048] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction - IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1  Build #IU-241.14494.240
2024-06-28 15:33:01,057 [7576048] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction - JDK: 17.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-06-28 15:33:01,057 [7576048] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction - OS: Windows 11
2024-06-28 15:33:01,057 [7576048] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction - Plugin to blame: Android version: 241.14494.240
2024-06-28 15:33:01,058 [7576049] SEVERE - #com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.runningdevices.actions.ToggleLayoutInspectorAction - Last Action: ShowLog
2024-06-28 15:33:01,222 [7576213]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Activated packet streamer for bluetooth emulation
2024-06-28 15:33:01,785 [7576776]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Camera notification event: cameraNotification { }
2024-06-28 15:33:01,786 [7576777]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Not yet booted
2024-06-28 15:33:01,887 [7576878]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorView - Received notification: cameraNotification { }
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - netsimd I 06-28 18:33:12.214 rust_main.rs:96 - netsim artifacts path: "C:\\Users\\ramal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\netsimd"
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - netsimd I 06-28 18:33:12.214 rust_main.rs:99 - NetsimdArgs {
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - fd_startup_str: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_cli_ui: true,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_web_ui: true,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - pcap: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - disable_address_reuse: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - hci_port: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - connector_instance: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - instance: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - logtostderr: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - dev: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,213 [7587204]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - vsock: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,214 [7587205]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - config: None,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,214 [7587205]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - test_beacons: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,214 [7587205]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_test_beacons: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,214 [7587205]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - no_shutdown: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,214 [7587205]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - version: false,
2024-06-28 15:33:12,214 [7587205]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - }
2024-06-28 15:33:15,083 [7590074]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Not yet booted
2024-06-28 15:33:15,083 [7590074]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Displaychange event:
2024-06-28 15:33:15,083 [7590074]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - 0
2024-06-28 15:33:15,083 [7590074]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Display notification event: event: DISPLAY_CONFIGURATIONS_CHANGED_UI displayConfigurationsChangedNotification { displayConfigurations { displays { width: 1080 height: 2340 dpi: 440 } userConfigurable: 3 maxDisplays: 11 } }
2024-06-28 15:33:15,085 [7590076]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorView - Received notification: event: DISPLAY_CONFIGURATIONS_CHANGED_UI displayConfigurationsChangedNotification { displayConfigurations { displays { width: 1080 height: 2340 dpi: 440 } userConfigurable: 3 maxDisplays: 11 } }
2024-06-28 15:33:15,623 [7590614]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.processnamemonitor.ProcessNameMonitorService - Adding emulator-5554
2024-06-28 15:33:15,761 [7590752]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.processnamemonitor.ProcessNameMonitorService - Agent tracker error
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2024.1\android\android-plugin-resources\231.0.26.0\plugins\android\resources\process-tracker-agent\native\x86_64\process-tracker
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:96)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsChannelFactory.newAsynchronousFileChannel(WindowsChannelFactory.java:209)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newAsynchronousFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:146)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(AsynchronousFileChannel.java:259)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(AsynchronousFileChannel.java:323)
    at com.android.adblib.impl.channels.AdbChannelFactoryImpl$openInput$2.invokeSuspend(AdbChannelFactoryImpl.kt:133)
    at com.android.adblib.impl.channels.AdbChannelFactoryImpl$openInput$2.invoke(AdbChannelFactoryImpl.kt)
    at com.android.adblib.impl.channels.AdbChannelFactoryImpl$openInput$2.invoke(AdbChannelFactoryImpl.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.adblib.impl.channels.AdbChannelFactoryImpl.openInput(AdbChannelFactoryImpl.kt:131)
    at com.android.adblib.impl.channels.AdbChannelFactoryImpl.openFile(AdbChannelFactoryImpl.kt:48)
    at com.android.adblib.AdbDeviceServicesKt.syncSend(AdbDeviceServices.kt:650)
    at com.android.adblib.AdbDeviceServicesKt.syncSend$default(AdbDeviceServices.kt:641)
    at com.android.processmonitor.agenttracker.AgentProcessTracker.pushAgent(AgentProcessTracker.kt:96)
    at com.android.processmonitor.agenttracker.AgentProcessTracker.access$pushAgent(AgentProcessTracker.kt:52)
    at com.android.processmonitor.agenttracker.AgentProcessTracker$pushAgent$1.invokeSuspend(AgentProcessTracker.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterResume(Scopes.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:102)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
2024-06-28 15:33:16,155 [7591146]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-06-28 15:33:16,770 [7591761] SEVERE - #com.android.emulator.ImageConverter - Native image converter library is not available
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to find image_converter.dll. Possibly corrupted Studio installation
    at com.android.emulator.ImageConverter.getLibLocation(ImageConverter.java:125)
    at com.android.emulator.ImageConverter.loadNativeLibrary(ImageConverter.java:100)
    at com.android.emulator.ImageConverter.<clinit>(ImageConverter.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorView$ScreenshotReceiver.onNext(EmulatorView.kt:1197)
    at com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorView$ScreenshotReceiver.onNext(EmulatorView.kt:1124)
    at com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController$DelegatingStreamObserver.onNext(EmulatorController.kt:726)
    at com.android.tools.idea.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onMessage(ClientCalls.java:465)
    at com.android.tools.idea.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:661)
    at com.android.tools.idea.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:646)
    at com.android.tools.idea.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.android.tools.idea.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-06-28 15:33:16,773 [7591764] SEVERE - #com.android.emulator.ImageConverter - IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1  Build #IU-241.14494.240
2024-06-28 15:33:16,773 [7591764] SEVERE - #com.android.emulator.ImageConverter - JDK: 17.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-06-28 15:33:16,774 [7591765] SEVERE - #com.android.emulator.ImageConverter - OS: Windows 11
2024-06-28 15:33:16,774 [7591765] SEVERE - #com.android.emulator.ImageConverter - Plugin to blame: Android version: 241.14494.240
2024-06-28 15:33:16,774 [7591765] SEVERE - #com.android.emulator.ImageConverter - Last Action: ShowLog
2024-06-28 15:33:17,225 [7592216]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-06-28 15:33:18,297 [7593288]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-06-28 15:33:19,502 [7594493]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - [20824:24716:20240628,153319.502:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\8779294c-7efa-43b9-a593-b4e0942808b7: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-06-28 15:33:19,503 [7594494]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - [20824:24716:20240628,153319.503:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\8779294c-7efa-43b9-a593-b4e0942808b7: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-06-28 15:33:19,503 [7594494]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - [20824:24716:20240628,153319.503:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
2024-06-28 15:33:19,702 [7594693]   INFO - #com.android.adblib.tools.debugging.impl.AppProcessTrackerImpl - AdbSession('ROOT') - ConnectedDevice(serial='emulator-5554') -Tracker services ended with expected EOF exception, retrying
2024-06-28 15:33:19,703 [7594694]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamScreenshot call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2024-06-28 15:33:19,703 [7594694]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamNotification call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2024-06-28 15:33:19,705 [7594696]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed
2024-06-28 15:33:19,705 [7594696]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - Disconnected from Pixel 4a API 34 (5554)
2024-06-28 15:33:19,706 [7594697]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554
java.lang.Throwable: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554
    at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher.handleException(PropertyFetcher.java:250)
    at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher.access$500(PropertyFetcher.java:31)
    at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:213)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: closed
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:654)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:511)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.executeShellCommand(DeviceImpl.java:740)
    at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:209)

2024-06-28 15:33:19,707 [7594698]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
2024-06-28 15:33:19,968 [7594959]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.processnamemonitor.ProcessNameMonitorService - Removing emulator-5554
2024-06-28 15:33:22,696 [7597687]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - [20824:24716:20240628,153322.696:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ramal\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\8779294c-7efa-43b9-a593-b4e0942808b7: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-06-28 15:33:22,721 [7597712]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-06-28 15:33:22,721 [7597712] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 4a API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819

The problem persist even with other SDKs, I tried 35, 30 and 31 but no use. I also tried to put the Graphics on Software or Hardware and not automatic, but also did nothing. I upped the RAM but no changes. I honestly don't know what else I can try. I thought maybe it could be something like the port the emulator uses is occupied, but tried looking and found nothing that caught my attention.
Does anyone have any idea?

It reads: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to find image_converter.dll, while it is unclear which version of Android Studio you are using. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220022493

As I can see the log suggests a successful emulator startup with some informative warnings about the development environment after that it stopped, so It seems to be an issue with the IDE itself, not the emulator. Any specific reason for not using android studio? There are warnings about deprecated usage of ActionUpdateThread.OLD_EDT by plugin. Maybe that is the reason of wired behaviour of emulator Pixel 4a.

@BobSmith Don't really have much of a reason to not install Android Studio, just don't want to install another software if I can do it inside of Intellij. I'm going to try using another emulated device and maybe install Android Studio.

As per logs IntelliJ is causing trouble to your emulator.

i suggest that try to use the genymotion instead of the android emulator.

The first two errors, Unable to find image_converter.dll and ActionUpdateThread.OLD_EDT is deprecated, are already on JetBrains YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-338869 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-344431 respectively. They have limited visibility and are not resolved yet. I asked developers to suggest a workaround. Installing Android Studio or a lower version of IntelliJ IDEA could very well be the workaround for now.

Hey @Koyasha thank you for letting me know. I tried installing Android Studio but the same thing keeps happening. Maybe I'll try and see if I can get the dll? Honestly idk

@ramalandajo Can confirm that, unfortunately, there's no workaround at the moment. Our Android developers are looking into the root cause. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon.
